# How to choose encoding type for the read_csv of pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have difficulties in finding the encoding type of the xlsx file. When I use pd.read_csv(file), it display an error("UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 15-16: invalid continuation byte").
Then I try to create a list of many encoding types to loop through, but still doesn't work.
The data looks like:
PK     ! b�h^  �   [Content_Types].xml �(�                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ���N�0E�H�C�-Jܲ@5��*Q>�ēƪc[�ii����B�j7���{2��h�nm���ƻR����U^7/���%��rZY�@1__�f� �q��R4D�AJ�h>����V�ƹ�Z�9����NV�8ʩ����ji){^��-I�"{�v^�P!XS)bR�r��K�s(�3�`c�0��������7M4����ZƐk+�|\|z�(���P��6h_-[�@�!��� Pk���2n�}�?�L��� ��%���d����dN"m,�ǞDO97*�~��ɸ8�O�c|n���E������B��!$}�����;{���[����2�  �� PK     ! �U0#�   L   _rels/.rels �(�                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ��MO�0��H�����ݐBKwAH�!T~�I����$ݿ'T�G�~����<���!��4��;#�w����qu*&r�Fq���v�����GJy(v��*����K��#F��D��.W ��=��Z�MY�b���BS����7��ϛז�� ?�9L�ҙ�sbgٮ|�l!��USh9i�b�r:"y_dl��D���|-N��R"4�2�G�%��Z�4�˝y�7 ë��ɂ���  �� PK     ! #K@��  J     xl/workbook.xml�U�n�0}_i���;�@TR�I����j{{A�p��`���EU�}�Ҧy�|������l]hɔ�RĘy1�ʌ�E�oo�� F�P��B
�
��l����J�Ǚ�� ��qnL��NsVR}$+&�2����j��J1��1S��y�[R.p���`����l"Ӻd´ �� }��Jwhe����ǺrRYV 1�7��2�.B*:+��5 �Z��G<h��$0U�TI-���ݖ���s    ���0�C껊-��᎕ ?�*�a�/`��4i5Z� xDv�|<<��ݵ�E��~��f�����\dܰ,��0�+������X�~��;���J���i]�r��?�;A��0%�ac)�p��g5�`�s    G��ߚ+��_��iDg���ժ��8Jn5��������l���%]u�䞍sj�⤓�c��^�;I�ҵu/X3N|�'�7H^����蚦6X.D�����8��N�WF!_N�C����  �ɶ�~    �"����<<���i0�p�A:��h�ƃ� ��d���y���F���ɷB��1�*L?躳/�y�B���>���4���:l��;�V�ERv���\drc����f�j��<39hr��aK����E�Ipb�t,��1�����8��c侢�\�@��h &���o��&��Ȟ�.3Ҥ��QJ���vv������?   �� PK     ! �>���   �   xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels �(�                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 �RMK�0���0w�v�t/"�U�ɴ)�&!3~��*�]X�K/o�y���v�5���+��zl�;o���b��G�����s�>��,�8��(%���"D�҆4j�0u2js��MY�˴���S쭂��� �)f���C����y��    I< y ���!+��E���fMy�k�����K�5=|�t ��G)�s墙�U��tB��)���,���f�����   �� PK     ! )>�\�� CU6    xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml���N�0E�H���}�8���!�!�kי4V��l��B�;� R7Vb'ϙ��\m�&��r��<�)+]�좢/Ϸ�JB��Y������L��/C   l�hcW2dF��u`�K�_���΃��$�Y��cf��tG(�1�4J�+6� ���hU~hF�3�/W�@:�!b����J�����:/�uo�PH��xx������������l���KvɄܓ���C��]��E�k�����v�O�xK�˗+UW�#�\y��A���g|��Vx�I��T����9e�I�W���D1
2��$�Ν[����S*;Ƚ�-��I
�X�8s�MձEB���n}j�F����

Comment: Have you tried `pandas.read_excel`?

Comment: Have you tried `pd.read_excel('YOUR-FILE', encoding='utf-8')`?

Answer (score 2):

The [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) function expects data in **comma-separated values**, or CSV, format. Excel saves files to `.xlsx` files, which are binary files containing Excel-specific data.

To create a file that this function can read, open the file in Excel and use *Save As* to save it to a `.csv` file. Make sure to **keep the original** as the CSV file will not contain any formatting (font, color, number format, etc.).

Alternatively, you can use [`read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) as mentioned in aozk's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) ?

Look at ***encoding*** parameter of [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) function or use [encode()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/encode) on your string

Or you can use [chardet](https://pypi.org/project/chardet/) library if you want detect text encoding